# Как работает noexcept в c++?

Tags: c++, исключения, c++11

Что делает спецификация noexcept? Я думал, что она не позволит функции кинуть исключение, но это не так, функция:

```
int Foo() noexcept
{
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
    return 0;
}
```

компилируется, её вызов спокойно падает, значит исключение вылетело. noexcept ничего не изменил.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Спецификатор `noexcept` дает гарантию времени компиляции, что из функции не будет выброшено исключение. Однако такая гарантия достигается эквивалентно оборачиванию тела функции в блок try...catch с вызовом `::std::terminate`:

```
int Foo() noexcept
{
    try
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("error");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        ::std::terminate();
    }
}
```

Определить, что в теле функции исключений действительно не выбрасывается и соптимизировать их перехват компиляторы могут только в самых простых случаях. Идея была в том, что оптимизацию сможет осуществить *вызывающий* код. Но на практике это все не работает и контроля над исключениями во время компиляции, особенно после выкидывания спецификаторов исключений, в с++ фактически нет.

Comment: Как минимум, работает оптимизация с noexcept move-ctor для `MyType` для `std::vector<MyType>`

Answer (score 7):

Этим **вы** как автор гарантируете, что ваша функция *не генерирует исключений*, так что компилятор может, полагаясь на это, выполнять ряд оптимизаций.

Понятно, что вы хозяин своему слову - сам дал, сам и назад забрал! Только потом не удивляйтесь результатам - завершению программы.

См., например, эту [статейку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/164221/).

Comment: Правильно ли я понял, что если я в функции, помеченной этим спецификатором, выкину исключение, то получу UB?

Comment: Получите вызов `std::terminate()`, насколько я помню.

Comment: То есть при вызове исключения в такой функции программа сразу аварийно завершается, и перехватить такое исключение не получится, верно?

Comment: Да, вот посмотрите: https://ideone.com/tvrDVo

Answer (score 3):

В С++ 11 безусловный модификатор noexcept применяется к функциям, которые гарантированно не могут генерировать исключения.
Должна ли функция быть объявлена таким образом - вопрос проектирования интерфейса.
Отсутствие объявления функции как noexcept, когда вы точно
знаете, что она не в состоянии генерировать исключения, - не более чем просто плохая спецификация интерфейса.
**Но есть и дополнительный стимул для применения noexcept к функциям, которые не
генерируют исключений: это позволяет компиляторам генерировать лучший объектный
код.**
В случае функции, объявленной как noexcept, оптимизаторам не надо ни поддерживать стек в сворачиваемом состоянии, ни гарантировать,
что объекты в такой функции будут уничтожены в порядке, обратном созданию,
если вдруг такую функцию покинет исключение.
Этого одного достаточно для того, чтобы объявлять функции, о которых точно известно,что они не генерируют исключений, как noexcept .
Литература из которой взят текст выше: https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34747131/