# Во что превращается C++::bool при экспорте из DLL с использованием extern "C"?

Tags: c++, c, dll, bool

Рассмотрим следующий код:

```
extern "C"
{
    bool func()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, что именно будет возвращать `func` при экспорте из `DLL`? Насколько я знаю, в `C` нет типа `bool`. Так же мне известно, что в `C` и `C++` все аргументы, типы которых меньше `int`, преобразуются к `int` (в большинстве операций).

Верно ли я понимаю, что использовать экспортированную из `DLL` функцию `func` я смогу через следующую сигнатуру:

```
int (*)()
```

Comment: во-первых то что в `c` нету типа `bool` относится к старым стандардам, в новых (не скажу точно с какого) этот тип имеется. Во-вторых, тип bool - это, по сути, int.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch А почему int, если `sizeof(bool)` обычно 1?

Comment: *"мне известно, что в C и C++ все аргументы, типы которых меньше int, преобразуются к int"* Откуда такая информация? Я знаю, что такое преобразование есть при передаче аргументов в именно в `...`-параметр (например в `printf`/`scanf`).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat да, действительно, равно 1... видимо я что-то перепутал, но мне казалось, что в `C` `bool` - это алиас `int`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, в `Стандарте` есть такой пункт, как `Integral Promotions`.

Comment: Я не утверждаю, что `bool` преобразуется к `int`, я как раз пытаюсь понять, что происходит на самом деле.

Comment: Думаю,  для большинства современных процессоров `int (*)()` работать будет. На всякий случай можно также `char (*)()`. На самом деле `func()` загрузит перед возвратом результат в младшие биты регистра, будут ли сохраняться старшие, зависит от компилятора.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструкция `extern "C"` задает только С linkage, то бишь делает возможность прилинковать этот модуль к модулю, написанному на С. Это выражается в том, что имя функции будет недекорированное, то бишь что в таблице экспорта будет записана функция с именем `func` безо всяких крякозябр. Однако сигнатура метода при этом никак не меняется. Так что `extern "C"` не означает что такую функцию можно будет вызвать из С кода.

Соответственно в данном случае `bool` ни во что не превращается. В C действительно нет типа `bool`. В диалекте С99 есть `_Bool`, однако это отдельный тип, никак не связанный с `bool`.  И они оба никак не связаны с `int`. Так что сигнатура `int (*)()` к ней не подходит, а использовать эту функцию из С не выйдет.
Если хотите использовать функцию из С, то надо

1. возвращать `int`
2. объявить функцию как `noexcept` или вручную перехватывать возможные исключения чтобы не допустить пересечения языковой границы при раскрутке стека.

> Так же мне известно, что в C и C++ все аргументы, типы которых меньше int, преобразуются к int.

Совсем не обязательно. Такие варварские преобразования могут иметь место при вызове встроенных арифметических операторов, которые не определены для мелких типов.

Comment: *"Использовать эту функцию из С не выйдет"* А если использовать сишный `_Bool`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat При желании наверное можно использовать любой целочисленный тип подходящего размера. Но это не очень хорошая затея. Если уж предоставлять С интерфейс, то предоставлять его с расчетом, что его смогут использовать не только программы на С, использующие расширения С99. И не только программы на С.

Comment: @user7860670, могу ли я не помечать функцию как `noexcept`? Я понимаю, что исключения не должны покидать функции, которые экспортируются с использованием `extern "C"`, но мне не совсем понятно, что будет, если я `noexcept` не укажу. На мой взгляд, факт того, что функция помечена `extern "C"`, уже говорит о том, что функция является функцией `C` и не генерирует исключения.

Comment: @MGNeo Можно и не помечать, но тогда придется обеспечить отсутствие исключений другим способом. `extern "C"` этого делать не будет

Comment: Достаточно ли внутреннего `try/catch`? Что конкретно делает `noexcept`? Да, я понимаю, что говорит о том, что функция/метод не генерирует исключение. Но что происходит `под капотом`?

Comment: @MGNeo https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812038/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-noexcept-%d0%b2-c