# Надо понять куда пихать noexcept, 2 совсем мелких вопроса + бонус вопрос для меня про(.inl)

Tags: c++, c++11

Есть файлы:

```
/*A.hpp для объявления*/
void sum();

/*A.inl для определения*/
void sum(){/*что-то*/};
```

Не очень понимаю, в каком файле ставить `noexcept`, то есть я уверен что исключений не будет, а так же понимаю что правильнее будет поставить в объявлении `void sum() noexcept;` и после в определении `void sum() noexcept {/*что-то*/};`.

Допустим с `inline` понятно. Если я поставлю в файле определения `inline`, то я попрошу компилятор встроить его в объявление. А если вставлю `inline` соответственно в объявлении, то компилятор мб встроит его когда буду вызывать уже где-то. *Тут вопросов нету*. (с `inline` просто пример,тут мне понятно)

**вопрос 1** Куда мне вставлять `noexcept`, в объявление или в определение? Выбираю ответ и туда и туда, но тут я не оч уверен Х)

**вопрос 2** Почему видя проекты написанные недавно, я замечаю что `noexcept` появляется очень редко или в прицепи его вообще нету. Ведь если я уверен что точно не будет исключения, почему не ускорить выполнение спамя `noexcept` везде где возможно?  (речь сейчас о моментах где уверен что не упадёт приложение)

**бонус-вопрос** Много чего видел и в этом многом часто используют разные форматы для разделения, оценил, удобно. Но несёт ли какой-то скрытый посыл использование формата `.inl` (конкретно этого формата) ?  (Спасибо @user7860670 подтолкнул на ответ,как я понял **Нет не несёт скрытого смысла** Вопрос отпрадает)

*Иногда попадаются такие тонкости и хз где находить подобное, вроде пишут, но не заостряют внимания на мелочах =)*

Comment: задавайте **один** вопрос в вопросе, причем 2 - дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812038/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-noexcept-%d0%b2-c/812045#812045 , 3 - дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/876163/c-%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/876207#876207

Comment: @user7860670 Вы читали что я написал? Прочтите пожалуйста) Я не спрашивал как работает `noexcept`. Так же,я написал что понимаю для чего `.inl` в данном коде и спросил есть ли скрытый смысл

Comment: ¿А вы читали, что я написал в тех ответах? Прочтите пожалуйста) Желательно даже несколько раз.

Comment: @user7860670 2 раза перечитал то что Вы написали,а так же до заданного вопроса видел эти вопросы, но не смотря на это ответа в них не нашёл. Ибо мне понятно что такое `noexcept` и `.inl` мне не понятны тонкости языка и их я написал в вопросе. Гуглил, того что нужно мне не нашёл, конечно я могу и без этого обойтись и писать не зная + лишь с догадками, но я хочу стать умнее.

Comment: @user7860670 Блин) Вот написать ответ на 3тий вопрос "нет скрытого смысла" трудно? Да, Вы правы, 3тий вопрос отпал, я думал использование `.inl` несёт что-то за собой помимо того что писал выше, спасибо что подтолкнули)

Comment: вопрос 1 - в двух местах. вопрос 2 - не нужно его цеплять везде. можно травмировать свою программу. Но вот в конструкторах и операторах перемещения очень желательно. Почему не используют? да потому что пишут на с++98 в лучшем случае.

Comment: вопрос 1 - то ли в C++11, то ли ранних версиях компиляторов с поддержкой C+11 можно было писать noexcept только в объявлении или в определении. Сейчас noexcept является частью типа, он должен быть и в объявлении, и в определении.

Comment: *`"Иногда попадаются такие тонкости и хз где находить подобное, вроде пишут, но не заостряют внимания на мелочах =)"`* -- это верно замечено, самым правильным выводом будет забить на кресты и использовать другие языки

Comment: @KoVadim травмировать? это как? Отпишите ответом,я поставлю галку)

Comment: @avp - и какой же язык теперь модный, в котором нет "тонкостей"?

Comment: @KoVadim, я предпочитаю старый добрый Си (в гнусном варианте)

Comment: Си хорош. Вот только большинство, кто пишет, что знает с/с++ не знает, ни того, ни другого.