# Смысл ключевого слова noexcept

Tags: c++

Реализую собственный unique ptr. И в википедии для реализации любого конструктора перемещения используется noexcept, для чего он нужен и какой его смысл?

```
UniquePtr &operator=(UniquePtr &&object) noexcept {
    if (&object == this) {
        return *this;
    }
    delete ptr_;

    ptr_ = object.m_ptr;
    object.m_ptr = nullptr;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Это говорит о том что конструктор не будет бросать исключения...

Comment: А какие исключения могут выброситься в данном случае?

Comment: похоже на дубликат https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812038/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-noexcept-%d0%b2-c